# how to filter a datagridview by the current date without time?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, datagridviewcolumn

I Really need your help guys , i created a table in sql and i displayed it in a datagridview that contains product and date(it's a datatime variable),but what i want is filter products by current date without time (i want products that refers just to the current date),here is the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k70Lv.png)

and here is the result , it does filter anything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjR0x.png)

Comment: For future reference, DO NOT post pictures of code or error messages. Post the text and format it appropriately. If we want to test or edit your code or search for your error message, we can't copy anything from a picture. Add a screenshot as well if it actually adds value, but never post JUST a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter by date and not time where there's no function to get just a date value from the data, the simplest option is to use a range. Assuming that you have a `DataTable`, you should bind it to your `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`, which you can add to the form in the designer. You could then filter based on the current date like so:

```cs
myBindingSource.Filter = $"DateTimeColumn >= #{DateTime.Now:M/dd/yyyy}# AND DateTimeColumn < #{DateTime.Now.AddDays(1):M/dd/yyyy}#"
```

That will produce a `string` like `"DateTimeColumn >= #10/02/2022# AND DateTimeColumn < #10/03/2022#"`, so match any time with today's date.